# Length of a spiral in polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, arc-length

Part of my assignment is to find out how to calculate the length of the spiral in the picture in polar coordinates( from point a to b) I wonder if someone can help me. We haven’t really done anything like that in the subject before.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Could you please type out the things in your image, as some other people cannot see it easily? Thank you! Also, type your equations using MathJax if necessary (in this case just write `$a$` for $a$ and `$b$` for $b$). Here is a link to a basic tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you know how to compute arc length?

Comment: You can calculate the length using this https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/helix-length

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

Coil diameter $2R$, pitch or one turn height $p$.

Length of each turn $= \sqrt{(2\pi R)^2+h^2}$ by screw/helix flattened  development and Pythagoras thm which is to be multiplied by

$$ n=\frac{\text{Coil height = H}}{h} $$

Can you sketch the development?